# boost python with pickle leaking

Tags: python, c++, boost, pickle

I'm currently developing a game. Most of the gameplay is in python and the time sensitive are coded is C++. Boost python 1.55 is the bridge.

I'm trying to serialize (pickle) IA class to send them on the network.

```
def update(self, elapsedTime):
   core.pushCommand("update_ia", pickle.dumps(self), self.manager)
```

As a testing purpose, this function is called each frame, meaning roughly 60 times per second.
And my game eats 100 mega of memory every few seconds and rapidly exiting due to memory exhaustion.

I've tried to use a different version of this code but ended with the same problem:

```
def update(self, elapsedTime):
    iostr = StringIO()
    p = pickle.Pickler(iostr)
    p.dump(self)
    core.pushCommand("update_ia", iostr.getvalue(), self.manager)
    iostr.close()
    p.clear_memo()
```

I also tried to use the native pickle module instead of cPickle with no benefit either.

Comment: Can you say why you think this should /not/ leak? How are you dealing with the serialised objects you create?

Comment: Actually I just send the string pickle.dumps() return over the network. I'm actually doing it for a lot of other "commands". And we are talking hundreds of mega every few seconds. By the way just replacing pickle.dumps() to any other strings value does not leak.

Comment: Ok, so are the things you've been dumping inside pickle being cleaned up automatically, or are you filling your pickle object with thousands of snapshots that are being saved for you?

Comment: I'm pickling the same object every frame, saving snapshot of this object. But all I do on the client side is to send this string over network. After sending, the string should be freed. Is this you what you were asking ?

Comment: Ok, have you tried pickling the object, but never dumping and sending the string, or alternatively dump the string to a temp variable before sending and see if the problem persists in either of those cases?

Comment: I've tried to dump the object to a temporary variable, but no difference whatsoever.

Comment: Ok, but did you try repeatedly pickling the object but never dumping the string representation?